# Struts2 jasperreports-plugin: unable to generate report using jdbc connection

Tags: java, jdbc, struts2, jasper-reports

i'm using the struts2 jasperreports-plugin and I'm trying to generate an HTML report invoking an action.

The .jasper file is generated using *iReport*.

I successfully generated the report using a List as datasource, but i'm getting some problems trying to use a *jdbc* connection.

This is what i've done following the [tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html).

```
public class JasperReportAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<User> users;
    //getters and setters

    public String getTestReport() {
        User u1 = new User();
        User u2 = new User();
       setSomeParameters(u1, u2);

        users.add(u1);
        users.add(u2);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And this is what i added in my struts.xml file:

```xml
<package name="jasperreport" namespace="/reports" extends="jasperreports-default">
    <action name="myJasperTest" class="[...]JasperReportAction" method="getTestReport">
        <result name="success" type="jasper" >
            <param name="location">report2.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">users</param> 
            <param name="format">HTML</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And this works. I have my report with the data defined in the list.
I've tried to modify my action to establish a *jdbc* connection, retrieving the data with a simple "select" query:

```
 public class JasperReportAction extends ActionSupport {
    private java.sql.Connection sqlConnection;
    //getters and setters..

    public String getTestReport() {
        try {
            sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "user", "pwd");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And in the *struts.xml* I changed the datasource to "sqlConnection".
As a result i get a report with only one row with null values.

I also tried to generate an output file using the same connection:

```
public String getTestReport() {
        try {
            sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "user", "pwd");

            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report2.jrxml");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(), sqlConnection);
             JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(print, "repo.html");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

When I invoke the action, the displayed report still contains null values, but the generated html file contains all the data stored in the table.

I'm new with *JasperReports* and I don't know if I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `struts2-jasperreports-plugin` [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html) in order to use JDBC connection you need to define it in `connection` parameter.

```
<package name="jasperreport" namespace="/reports" extends="jasperreports-default">
    <action name="myJasperTest" class="[...]JasperReportAction" method="getTestReport">
        <result name="success" type="jasper" >
            <param name="location">report2.jasper</param>
            <param name="connection">sqlConnection</param> 
            <param name="format">HTML</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Also don't forget to create getter/setter for `sqlConnection`.

Comment: Thank you! i didn't pay much attention to the connection parameter, i was focusing only on the dataSource.. :)